# I don't get why odd = !odd is used here and what is use of it?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I don't get why odd =! odd is used here and what is use of it is it mean odd =! false or odd=!true, odd==false??

```
int [] res = new int[n];
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        
        boolean odd=false;
        int t=0, k=n-1;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            if(odd)
            {
                res[i] = arr[k];
                k--;
                
            }
            else
            {
                res[i]=arr[t];
                t++;
            }
            
            **odd =! odd;**
        }
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                arr[i]=res[i];
                
            }
```

Comment: It sets `odd` to the opposite of its previous value.

Comment: `odd = !odd` means you invert the boolean flag. Like you say "Assign a value the is opposite to `odd` to `odd` itself"

Comment: A boolean variable may only have two values, true or false. So setting ```odd = !odd;`` just sets odd to the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's right that means just assign the complement (!) value to it.

If `odd` is `true` make it `false` and if it's `false` make it `true`.